# How to get each row value from excel sheet in a directory using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

Sample Excel:

```
name   empid   office
ABC    1111     CTS
XYZ    2222     TCS
```

I want the values in dictionary like :

```
row1={ name='ABC', empid=1111, office='CTS' }
row2={ name='XYZ', empid=2222, office='TCS' }
```

using loops, one row at a time.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel('E://Python Workspace//pythonReadExcel.xlsx',  skiprows=0)
print(dfs.to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'name': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'XYZ'}, 'empid': {0: 1111, 1: 2222}, 'office': {0: 'CTS', 1: 'TCS'}}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code:

```py
df.to_dict(orient='records')

#output
[
  {'empid': 1111, 'name': 'ABC', 'office': 'CTS'}, 
  {'empid': 2222, 'name': 'XYZ', 'office': 'TCS'}
]
```